# Is there any way to grant a Flask app access to COM ports in windows?

Tags: python, flask, arduino

I wanted to make a Flask server that receives data from an android app, and then sends data over serial to an arduino connected via USB. However, I can't seem to be able to access the COM port where the arduino is connected.

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Api, Resource, reqparse
import serial 

# Initialize serial streams
serCam = serial.Serial('COM3', baudrate=9600, timeout=1)
if not serCam.isOpen():
    serCam.open()

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

## Here there are flask requests...

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

And the error is this one:
"serial.serialutil.SerialException: could not open port 'COM3': PermissionError(13, 'Access is denied.', None, 5)"

I have checked that I am trying to connect to the correct port using the arduino terminal and using the same serial related code in another script. I did not forget to close any other serial connections. I also ran the python script with administrator rights, as I read that on windows the COM port privileges are sometimes locked to normal users on windows, but it still doesn't work as I believe Flask starts a subprocess that no longer has admin privileges.

So is there any way to grant COM port access to a flask application without granting all the root privileges?

Comment: Are you using `pyserail`? Please add your code to show what you've done so far.

Comment: yes, I am using `pyserial`. I added the code

Comment: You mentioned about subprocess. Could that be the possibility that the port is already in used by a previous process? Try to disabled the COM port in the Device Manager window and enabled it again.

Comment: no, I am sure the COM port is not used as I did disable and enable it back again. I am quite sure the subprocess does not have root privileges on windows, so I probably need to somehow run the Flask app with root privileges (which, however, I assume is a bad idea in general)

Answer (score 0):

It should help to do threaded=True in the Flask run call.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation).

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.